# Iterating through list by DateTime property

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List and I need to calculate average of Value for each day by Created. How can I elegantly iterate the list for each day presented in the list? There can be gaps in the days and varying number of objects for each day.

For example values could be something like these:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

{ Value: 1, Created: 2018-07-01 12:00:00 }
{ Value: 4, Created: 2018-07-01 20:00:00 }
{ Value: 2, Created: 2018-07-03 12:00:00 }
{ Value: 3, Created: 2018-07-04 09:00:00 }
{ Value: 2, Created: 2018-07-04 11:00:00 }
{ Value: 6, Created: 2018-07-04 12:00:00 }
{ Value: 5, Created: 2018-07-06 16:00:00 }
{ Value: 3, Created: 2018-07-06 11:00:00 }
```

I could go for something like this...

```
List<MyObject> items = itemsfrombackend;
DateTime beginDay = items.First().Created;
DateTime endDay = items.Last().Created;
for (DateTime day = beginDay; day <= endDay; day.AddDays(1))
{
    // if items contains any matching objects calculate avg
}
```

But would like to find a simpler way with less ifs

Comment: Would you please provide the desired result too?

Comment: In the values above the desired result would be 2.5, 2, 3.7 and 4.

Comment: @crazysnake how about 2018-07-05? zero or not existing?

Comment: @fubo not existing. Missing dates should not be regarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to [group the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb384063(v=vs.110)) and calculate averages. You can use [DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the date part of a DateTime value,eg :

```
var averages=items.GroupBy(grp=>grp.Created.Date)
        .Select(grp=>new {Date=grp.Key,Average=grp.Average(it=>it.Value)});
```

Or in query form:

```
var averages=from item in items
             group item by item.Created.Date into grp
             select new { Date=grp.Key,
                          Average=grp.Average(it=>it.Value)
                        };
```

`GroupBy` creates a "bucket" of items that share the same key. That bucket can be treated as a collection, allowing you to filter it, pick individual items or calculate aggregate functions based on its contents, like [Averabe()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.queryable.average(v=vs.110).aspx).

Many of the One of the `Average()` overloads allow you to [specify the property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548770(v=vs.110).aspx) you want to use for the calculation.

```
grp.Average(it=>it.Value)
```

Selectes and averages the contents of the `Value` of the items found in each group's bucket

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `GroupBy()` combined with `Average()`

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Created.Date)
                  .Select(x => new { Created = x.Key, Avg = x.Average(y => y.Value) });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it completely using LINQ as others mentioned. You can try this method too, which has some LINQ ;-)

```
Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> avg = new Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>();

foreach (MyObject obj in items)
{
    if (avg.ContainsKey(obj.Created.Date))
    {
        avg[obj.Created.Date] += (decimal)obj.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        avg.Add(obj.Created.Date, (decimal)obj.Value);
    }
}

foreach (var item in avg.ToList())
{
    avg[item.Key] =Math.Round(item.Value / items.Count(x => x.Created.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(item.Key).Date),1);
}
```